# How to Save an array index data to database in separate row?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

**I have a featureds table (foreign key= product_id) that belongsto products table, Now i want to save some products id to my featured table,its give me a array reasult but i couldnot save it to database**

Here is my Controller -->

```js
  public function featuredProduct(Request $request)
   {
       if($request->isMethod('POST')){
         $product_id=$request->all();
         foreach ($product_id as $product) {
            $products[]=$product;
         }
         //dd($products);
       Featured::create($products);
       }
       return view('admin.products.featured');
   }
```

```html
<form action="{{ route('featuredProduct') }}" method="POST" multiple>
  <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap verticle_middle">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="{{ $product->id }}" value="{{ $product->id }}" type="checkbox" name="product[]">
          <label for=id={{ $product->id }}>{{ $product->product_name }}</label>
        </td>
        <td> {{ $product->category['cat_name'] }} </td>
        <td> <img src="{{asset($product->pro_img) }}" alt="" width="40"> </td>
        <td class="center">
        @if ($product->status === 1)
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Published</span>
        @else
            <span class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Unpublish</span>
        @endif
        </td>
        </tr>
          @endforeach
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button"class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create each feature inside the for loop.

```
public function featuredProduct(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        foreach($request->all() as $productId) {
            Featured::create([
                'product_id' => $productId,
                ... other data fields.
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to save all the features at once.

```
public function featuredProduct(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $featureds = [];

        foreach($request->all() as $productId) {
            $featureds[] = [
                'product_id' => $productId,
                ... other data fields.
            ]
        }

        DB::table('featureds')->insert($featureds);
    }
}
```

Comment: @tharaka_Dilshan its return me a blank page 

Comment: thanks its work for me! love from bangladesh  i am new in proggraming its helped me a lot.